# Expected expression before 'Node'

Tags: c

I've been messing aroung with the linked list implementation in C and got stuck at this problem: why is it giving me `expected expression before 'Node'` in the following lines?:

```
Node *newNode1= malloc(sizeOf(Node));
Node *newNode2= malloc(sizeOf(Node));
Node *newNode3= malloc(sizeOf(Node));
Node *newNode4= malloc(sizeOf(Node));
```

I've never seen such problems in C before. What went wrong ?
**`Code`**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node_{
    int data;
    struct Node_ *next;
}Node;

void insertNodeBegin(Node **head, Node *newNode){
    if((*head)==NULL){
        (*head)->next = NULL;
        *head = newNode;
    }
    else{
        newNode->next = (*head)->next;
        (*head)->next = newNode;
    }
}

void printList(Node *head){
    Node *current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%d ", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = NULL;

    Node *newNode1= malloc(sizeOf(Node));
    newNode1->data = 12;

    Node *newNode2 = malloc(sizeOf(Node));
    newNode2->data = 16;

    Node *newNode3 = malloc(sizeOf(Node));
    newNode3->data = 55;

    Node *newNode4 = malloc(sizeOf(Node));
    newNode4->data = 8;

    insertNodeBegin(&head, newNode1);
    insertNodeBegin(&head, newNode2);
    insertNodeBegin(&head, newNode3);
    insertNodeBegin(&head, newNode4);

    printList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if((*head)==NULL){
        (*head)->next = NULL;` : `NULL->next = NULL;` will cause a segment fault.

Comment: Because `NULL` does not point the `Node` object. also `newNode->next` uninitialize.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sizeOf(Node)` should be `sizeof(Node)`, note the small `o`.  After all this is C, not Java.  :)

Comment: OMG! How could i forgot that!

Comment: Now it's crashing when trying to run, any ideas why it's crashing ? @JohnZwinck

Comment: @KemalP. problem is in `insertNodeBegin()` function

Answer (score 0):

In short reorder if commands inside `insertNodeBegin()`

```
if(*head == NULL){
    *head = newNode;
    (*head)->next = NULL;
}
```

Because in first execution of program head points to NULL and for it we haven't any allocated memory. As head in first execution not points to a Node location using `head -> next` not valid and cause segmentation fault in run time.

In node creation with `malloc()` we must check is memory allocation successful or not. for that i use `createNode()` function.

We check if memory allocation for Node is OK then add that Node to list. And finally Use void as main(**void**) argument.

After these change your code becomes

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node_{
    int data;
    struct Node_ *next;
}Node;


void insertNodeBegin(Node **head, Node *newNode){

    if(*head == NULL){
        *head = newNode;
        (*head)->next = NULL;
    }
    else{
        newNode->next = (*head)->next;
        (*head)->next = newNode;   
    }
}

void printList(Node *head){
    Node *current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%d ", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int createNode(Node **node, int value){

    *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(*node){
        (*node)->data = value;
        return 1;
    }else{
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", "can't allocate ...\n");
        return 0;
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    Node *head = NULL;

    Node *newNode1;  
    Node *newNode2;
    Node *newNode3;  
    Node *newNode4;

    if(createNode(&newNode1, 12)) {
        insertNodeBegin(&head, newNode1);
    }

    if(createNode(&newNode2, 16)) {
        insertNodeBegin(&head, newNode2);
    }

    if(createNode(&newNode3, 55)) {
        insertNodeBegin(&head, newNode3);
    }

    if(createNode(&newNode4, 8)) {
        insertNodeBegin(&head, newNode4);
    }


    printList(head);

    return 0;
}
```